# IF there is an overlap with a date range, return value from row with overlap

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, return, overlap

I am attempting to return a value a specific value in excel if there is a date overlap between two different rows. There is a requirement that another cell matches, this would be an ID but only return the value for a second ID also listed.

I have a report where column 1 is the name ID, column 2 is the project id and column 3 and 4 are the start and end dates.

If there is an overlap of dates based on name ID, I want excel to return the project id from column 2 of the row that is committing the overlap.
[Example of desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWahr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this in Excel*, but it would be fairly straightforward in SQL - is that an option? If it is, you need an ID column - just a simple incremented integer.

Also, you need to specify what happens if there is more than one other overlapping entry.

- unless you like writing complex functions and/or navigating Excel's rather tortuous SQL option.